# Clicking on NSMenu item causes a crash

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have problem I cannot find the cause. I have menu and application crashes as soon as app name menu item, or File or Edit is selected. Other 4 menu options work fine.

I cannot track the error, since the crash occurs as soon as you select menu drop down, you actually don't even come so far to select a menu option.

This is declaration code:

```
    IBOutlet NSMenu *miFile;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miNewProduct;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miDeleteProduct;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miDataupdateUndo;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miExit;

IBOutlet NSMenu *miEdit;

IBOutlet NSMenu *miExtra;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miSettings;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miFilestoreCleanup;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miEAN;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miBeatport;

IBOutlet NSMenu *miInvoice;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miInvoicePreview;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miInvoiceEnd;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miInvoiceExport;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miAccounting;

IBOutlet NSMenu *miStockList;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miServerRecieve;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miExport;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miImportModule;

IBOutlet NSMenu *miHelp;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miSendProtocol;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miHelpLink;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miReleaseNotes;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miCheckUpdate;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miRebeatDotCom;
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *miAbout;
```

Does anybody have an idea, what could cause a crash? It is EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash, I have used all Intsruments tools and found nothing...

Here is assembly code at point of crash if useful:

```
0x00007fff8461d39c  <+0000>  push   %rbp
0x00007fff8461d39d  <+0001>  mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x00007fff8461d3a0  <+0004>  push   %r14
0x00007fff8461d3a2  <+0006>  push   %rbx
0x00007fff8461d3a3  <+0007>  mov    (%rdi),%rbx   ///CRASH
0x00007fff8461d3a6  <+0010>  cmp    %rsi,%rbx
0x00007fff8461d3a9  <+0013>  je     0x7fff8461d3c6     <_ZN11TCFRetainedIPK8__CTFontE6RetainES2_+42>
0x00007fff8461d3ab  <+0015>  mov    %rdi,%r14
0x00007fff8461d3ae  <+0018>  test   %rsi,%rsi
0x00007fff8461d3b1  <+0021>  je     0x7fff8461d3be <_ZN11TCFRetainedIPK8__CTFontE6RetainES2_+34>
0x00007fff8461d3b3  <+0023>  mov    %rsi,%rdi
0x00007fff8461d3b6  <+0026>  callq  0x7fff8469c642 <dyld_stub_CFRetain>
0x00007fff8461d3bb  <+0031>  mov    %rax,%rsi
0x00007fff8461d3be  <+0034>  mov    %rsi,(%r14)
0x00007fff8461d3c1  <+0037>  test   %rbx,%rbx
0x00007fff8461d3c4  <+0040>  jne    0x7fff8461d3cb <_ZN11TCFRetainedIPK8__CTFontE6RetainES2_+47>
0x00007fff8461d3c6  <+0042>  pop    %rbx
0x00007fff8461d3c7  <+0043>  pop    %r14
0x00007fff8461d3c9  <+0045>  pop    %rbp
0x00007fff8461d3ca  <+0046>  retq   
0x00007fff8461d3cb  <+0047>  mov    %rbx,%rdi
0x00007fff8461d3ce  <+0050>  pop    %rbx
0x00007fff8461d3cf  <+0051>  pop    %r14
0x00007fff8461d3d1  <+0053>  pop    %rbp
0x00007fff8461d3d2  <+0054>  jmpq   0x7fff8469c63c <dyld_stub_CFRelease>
0x00007fff8461d3d7  <+0059>  nop
```

Menu was created completely in IB. it is ran on 10.7.2. Crashes on 10.6 as well. Uses GC. No  Zombies, Allocations, leaks or any other things that can be caught with Instruments of whatsoever - I need to repeat this obviously...

Comment: This isn't enough detail. Post the backtrace of the crash. Also, the best instrument for EXC_BAD_ACCESS is going to be Zombies. Make it crash then post the details Instruments finds about the messaged zombie. This is a memory management bug and it's exceedingly unlikely it's not yours. You really need to post all the detail you can.

Comment: "I have used all Intsruments tools and found nothing..." What part of this statement was not understood? I was obviously clear enough for you to realize that it is most probably internal error. It can be MM problem, but not visible or created by user if event of click creates it. Menu items are defined and connected same as for other 4 menu lines.

Comment: Until you edited your question after my response, all we knew is you "tried it and didn't find anything" but this is *not* enough detail. Any time someone insists it's a framework error without proof to back it up, alarm bells go off. You've shown nothing yet to demonstrate it's not your code. You'd do well to grow a thicker hide if you want to ask a developer community for help.

Comment: It's most probably a bug. Crashes app as soon as Key Alternative is set to menu item. It crashes only on Lion and not with new projects, but converted from old Xcode versions. Doesn't happen if file designation is .nib. It may be something wrong with the code, but handling this is most probably a bug. hope it help somebody although designated as not the real question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not comment about your code by only seeing interface file. you should refer [MenuItemView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MenuItemView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004136-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) code. "MenuItemView" is a Cocoa application that demonstrates embedding NSViews inside NSMenuItems. This sample is intended to show how this is done with various user interface elements such as controls as well as the application's menu bar. you can also refer 
[First Steps in GNUstep GUI Programming: NSApplication, NSMenu](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFsQFjAH&url=http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/Download/FirstGUIApplication.ps.gz&ei=HSOUTu_0CcXhrAfR_7WrBg&usg=AFQjCNFNFUoVoHcugsTIMmEvQjGrVcLFew&sig2=Znl5RK3pg6tQMpuHu2Empw).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I have posted declaration of code to try to avoid unfair rating for like not posting any code. I know how to build menus and I haven't had this kind of problem till now. It is possibly that problem persist only in 10.7, but this is not the only project I have in Lion and I haven't had similar problems...